# Prevent orphaned words with Tailwind?

Tags: tailwind-css, typography

Is there a way in CSS (specifically Tailwind) of preventing orphaned words in a block of text?

I can achieve this with a `&nbsp;` but I believe their is a CSS solution.

```
<p>This is my text that I dont want an orphaned word&nbsp;for</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `<span></span>` such as:
`<p>This is my text that I don't want an orphaned <span style="white-space: nowrap ;">word for</span></p>`
or
`<p>This is my text that I don't want an orphaned <span class="nowrap">word for</span></p>`

With CSS like:
`span.nowrap { white-space: nowrap ; }`